# Литература по системному программированию (Unix, Python)

Tags: python, книги, unix, linux

Добрый день!

Я на данный момент где-то чуть больше полугода учусь программировать на Python, а сейчас, в связи новым местом работы, возникла необходимость подтянуть на адекватный уровень системное программирование в никсах. Сам я в них разбираюсь на уровне чуть-чуть выше нуля, т.к. раньше практически всё делал в винде, плюс к этому непосредственно системным программированием не занимался.

Собственно вопрос - что можно в этой области почитать для начального уровня? Интересуют в первую очередь сами никсы - чтобы и основные команды шелла в голове уложить, и немного с башем покопаться, но не лишними будут и книги, касающиеся именно системного программирования на питоне.

Пробовал почитать Немет, Снайдер и др., но это не совсем то, что нужно - там всё-таки разбирается именно администрирование, к тому же требующее либо изначально неплохих знаний, либо возможности всё это как-то потрогать и посмотреть хотя бы на рабочих живых серверах.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: себе линукс уже установили?

Comment: Да, но на виртуальной машине. Ubuntu и FreeBSD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Лично я изучал Python по туториалу и документацию, при этом решая различные прикладные задачи по автоматизации процессов сборки и тестирования. Если обобщить, то любой язык или технологию именно так и стоит изучать, при этом каждый выбирает интересную или полезную для себя сферу его применения.

Системные программы пишут обычно на языке C, его знание в этой области - обязательно. Но на Python действительно легко изучать различные системные API в Linux/Unix, так как он предоставляет к ним прямой доступ через встроенный модуль `os`, но при этом надо обязательно заглядывать в man-страницы целевой ОС(man, вторая секция, например *man 2 open*).

Но для того, чтобы уложить и обобщить все полученные сведения в голове, я считаю, что нужно прочитать несколько хороших книжек.

По Python рекомендую [Марка Лутца](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5730448/), лучше конечно в оригинале, ибо сам читал на английском:

По Unix, Linux:

1. Общее понимание работы операционных систем, классика жанра: [Танненбаум](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6140231/)
2. Для начинающих юниксоидов неплохо почитать [Грэма Гласса](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1898064/)
3. Для понимания философии Unix неплохо почитать [Эрика Реймонда](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2317804/)
4. Программирование в Unix неплохо изложено в книге [Рочкинда](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2355792/)

Answer (score 3):

Классика - [Стивенсон](http://www.books.ru/books/unix-professionalnoe-programmirovanie-fail-pdf-595118/?show=1), незаменимая настольная книга каждого юниксоида
так же есть еще двухтомник Стивенсона "сетевое Программирование" и "многопоточное Программирование". Тоже желательно иметь их под рукой... Первые две книги мнге очень помогли, все можно найти на торрентах

И еще есть книга "системное программирование на Python" автора не помню... не плохое издание

Answer (score 1):

Советую установить дома на виртуалке какой-нибудь Linux, но не из коробки, а что-то такое кондовое типа [Slackware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slackware).

Попробуйте далее на него натянуть графическую оболочку на базе X-Window. Столкнетесь с тучей проблем, которые придется решать (администрировать). Можно придумывать и другие задачки: типа расшаривания папок с Линуха на ноутбук ребенка, подцепиться к холодильнику через wifi, сбацать DLNA сервер с выводом на TV - да мало ли. Смысл в том, что по ходу решения проблем вы натаскаетесь и сразу будет понятно какие книги понадобятся.

Чтение книг по администрированию, без доступа к реальной оси это в общем-то извращение.

**Update:** Ubuntu не подойдет - там все вопросы в основном уже решены, надо покондовее.

Comment: Чуть выше уже комментировал - у меня и так подняты Ubuntu и FreeBSD, как раз под Virtual Box'ом. Так что доступ к оси всё-таки есть. 
Не могли бы вы прокомментировать, чем именно Slackware будет лучше вышеперечисленных для обучения?

Comment: Ubuntu - серверная, граф. оболочку натягивал уже сам.

Comment: >  чем именно Slackware будет лучше вышеперечисленных для обучения?

точно тем же, чем газ-52 лучше мерседеса. Все очень зависит от условий.

Comment: @Barmaley извините, со Slackware у меня воспоминания только из 90х. Там мнение о системе было очень простое: "Меньше надо пить" (это о стиле работы мэйнтенера этого дистрибутива). Советовать такое чудо человеку, который мне ничего плохого не сделал, я бы не стал.

Comment: Именно поэтому и надо ставить Slackware что его надо править напильником и причем конкретно править. Все делается руками - только поэтому.

Comment: @Barmaley, нельзя с детьми так жестоко

Comment: LFS пусть соберет, если руками отправляете все делать.